# Pc runs slow suddently

Tags: windows, desktop-computer

Recently I have had sudden complications with my pc. From one day to the other it started to run really slow, mainly noticable with games. It also began to have the tendacy to shut itself down randomly to restart without any problems. Untill one day my pc booted up in 800*600 resolution. Turns out the videocard was broken. I throught this was the main problem. also my download speed seems to suddently have dropped from 12 mb/s to 1mb if I am lucky.

So I got a new card, a MSI 1050 gtx 4GB. The problem with the resolution seems fixed, but the pc still ran very slow and had trouble starting programs. I have tried to clean up both my drives (I have a 200 GB SSD on which windows runs and a 1TB hdd for my other files), Defragged them both, I have reset windows to factory settings via the settings, wiping all files. The pc runs a lot smoother now, but still it does not run programs well, especially heavier ones like the games. most of the times they do not even start and when they do they either crash or have trouble loading maps. I formatted my hdd as was suggested on a forum, but it doesn't seem to help.

I am out of idea's to try. Do any of you have any idea what it could be? And what could have caused my internet to drop. I only use an ethernet cable.

Thanks in andvance

Comment: Can you please share more details about your pc?

Comment: "I formatted my hdd as was suggested on a forum, but it doesn't seem to help." Did you formatted your HDD (with the data) or your SSD (with the OS)?

Comment: Rule out a heat problem; check heat sinks and fans for an accumulation of dust.

Comment: Have you checked for malware? Also, try booting from USB (e.g. Linux distro)... if there are still issues, it's likely hardware. If not, it's OS (or HDD/SSD - specific HW issue)..

Answer (score -1):

> Do any of you have any idea what it could be?

Unfortunately, no. Usually, I do a complete Re-Install of Windows in that case, because it is often impossible to determine the root cause of that deficiency. Consequently, this means copying all data/save files to the 1TB drive and do a complete new install of the OS on the the SSD.

Selecting the files to be saved/copied to the second drive will take some time.
They include

- Browser configuration, bookmarks, and notes of extensions
- Mail program configuration data
- Savegames for games
- Pictures/Audios/Videos in the corresponding folders
- Registry manipulations done
- Any config files/key files that you can think of
- Make sure that you have all passwords copied to some paper/a permanent file.

Then ReInstall without overwriting the data disk.

Comment: OP wrote in the original post that they already did it. _"I have reset windows to factory settings via the settings, wiping all files"_, _"I formatted my hdd as was suggested on a forum, but it doesn't seem to help."_

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you had a very unlucky day having multiple failures occur at the same time.
As a software engineering student I would check the RAM and the CPU for any damage.
You said that you've already formatted and cleaned your SSD and your HDD so I assume that non of them are close to being filled up all the way.

- The brain of your computer is the CPU. Check the speeds, the temperatures, maybe the CPU isn't cooling off enough or maybe its damaged in some way
- The second thing I would check is the RAM. When the CPU needs something that has been written on the memory (SSD/HDD), it is being loaded into the RAM. Since you checked your SSDs and your HDDs, I would recommend to also check the RAM sticks and make sure that they are also working properly. That you haven't moved them when working on the GPU (Graphics Processing Unit)

If you happen to have any more information to better guide me towards solving your issue, just comment here.
Hope I managed to help a little,
Good Luck!